# First Order Logic, help in transforming from english

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

i have to translate

"A student passed the exam of a class if he studies at least a textbook for that class"

My FOL representation is:

$\forall x$ $\forall c$ [Student(x) $\Rightarrow$ [$\exists y$ Textbook(y) $\land$ TextOf(y,c)  $\land$ Study(x,y)] $\Rightarrow$ Pass (x,c)]

Do you think is right?

---

Another question:

If i have

$\forall x$ A(x) $\Rightarrow$  B(x)

and i have to negate it, this will become

a) $\neg$ $\forall x$ A(x) $\Rightarrow$  B(x)

and hence : $\exists x$ $\neg$ [A(x) $\Rightarrow$  B(x)]

or

b)  $\forall x$  $\neg $ [A(x) $\Rightarrow$ B(x)]

I mean where do i have to apply the negation?

thanks

Comment: Your first expression is of the form $A\implies B\implies C$ (after the two quantifiers). This is ambiguous and you should add brackets.

Comment: i edited, know is better

Comment: The problem I pointed at still remains. You have two $\implies$, one after the other, without brackets to clarify which is applied first. You do have brackets around $B$, which is nice, but it's still $A\implies [B]\implies C$

Comment: Also you have no restriction on the domain of $c$.